# Django user's privete message system. User deletion handling

Tags: django, message

I wants to create user's private message application.
Message model would looks like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    mssg_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'message_from')
    mssg_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'message_to')
    text = models.TextField()
    reciver_deleted = BooleanField( default = False )
    sender_deleted = BooleanField( default = False )
    delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False)'message_from')
```

I want to delete message from database only when both users deleted it.
I know how to do it in view (it's why I created boolean fields) but...
What if I delete a user? how to handle it?
I want messages to be still avaliable for an user even if secound user was deleted.
But if I delete an user and let message still exist then one of ForeignKey would refer to user that doesn't exist.
How to handle with this kind of situations?

Comment: If you don't want to change your db scheme, probably you would like to add a fake user, and associate a message for a deleted user to this one, until the other user (the remaining real one) deletes the message.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your FK fields to:

```
    mssg_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'message_from', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    mssg_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'message_to', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

then when you delete one of the users, the corresponding field will be set to NULL.